# Cannot start a script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(<man.txt)
echo "$value"

if [ "$value" == "true" ]; then
    echo "startedif_manthan"
      ps -ef|grep sym |awk '{ print $2 }'|sudo  xargs kill -9;
      sleep 30;
    sudo sh /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym --port 8082 --server;
fi
```

Hi There, I have this script killing a process and restart the script in some time.
 It is killing the script normally but the restart script (sudo sh /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym --port 8082 --server) is not running properly.
 when I run the script manually also it is giving problems.
 I don't know whether it is a shell script or not.
 But when I tried to go manually to the script location and execute this command ./sym --port 8082 --server the script running normally.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the error message you get when you execute the shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say it works OK when you `cd` to the script directory, then do that in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(<man.txt)
echo "$value"

if [ "$value" == "true" ]
then
    echo "startedif_manthan"
    ps -ef|grep sym |awk '{ print $2 }'|sudo  xargs kill -9
    sleep 30
    (cd /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin; sudo sh ./sym --port 8082 --server)
fi
```

Comment: I tried it. It is killing process and it it not running the script in the brackets.

Comment: I got it, bcoz the script itself is matching the pattern to kill it is killing itself

Comment: It might be killing the `grep sym`...be very careful about matching too many processes.  A trick I use is `grep '[s]ym'`; the square bracket means it won't match itself, but will match the `sym` process.  But I'd still worry about `sym` appearing in other processes.